# Crank-Nicholson for diffusion-advection vs diffusion equation

Tags: finite-difference, advection-diffusion, differential-equations, diffusion, crank-nicolson

Let's consider the following 1D diffusion equation:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = xk \frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{1}{x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})$

where we assume that the diffusion coefficient $k$ is constant.

In order to discretize this equation, let us define the following:

$x_i = 1 + i\Delta x, \forall i=0,1,...,I \\
t_n = n\Delta t, \forall n=0,1,...,N \\
r = \frac{k\Delta t}{2 \Delta x^2} \\
s = \frac{k\Delta t}{4 \Delta x}
$

where $\Delta t$ and $\Delta x$ are the time step and the spacing, respectively.

Let's discretize the diffusion equation by means of the [Crank-Nicholson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method):

$u_i^{n+1}-u_i^n = r x_i [ \frac{u_{i+1}^n - u_i^n}{x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}} - \frac{u_i^n - u_{i-1}^n}{x_{i-\frac{1}{2}}}] + r x_i [ \frac{u_{i+1}^{n+1} - u_i^{n+1}}{x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}} - \frac{u_i^{n+1} - u_{i-1}^{n+1}}{x_{i-\frac{1}{2}}}]$

where upper indexes refer to time, lower indexes refer to space.

So far, so good. Now, using the product rule, the initial diffusion equation can be rewritten as:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = k \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} - \frac{k}{x}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$

The latter equation is now a diffusion-advection equation, but should be equivalent to the original diffusion equation.

Let us discretize the latter equation by means of the [Crank-Nicholson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crank%E2%80%93Nicolson_method):

$u_i^{n+1}-u_i^n = r [ u_{i+1}^n - 2 u_i^n + u_{i-1}^n ] - \frac{s}{x_i} [ u_{i+1}^n - u_{i-1}^n] + r [ u_{i+1}^{n+1} - 2 u_i^{n+1} + u_{i-1}^{n+1}] - \frac{s}{x_i} [u_{i+1}^{n+1} - u_{i-1}^{n+1}]$

Those 2 discretizations are different. So, here is my question:

Which discretization should I choose?

Comment: You really do have a variable coefficient heat equation as written so I am not surprised that you are seeing different discretizations as is common for variable coefficient problems.  Looking at the two discretizations I would pick the latter but it may not be consistent with the original equation.

Comment: @KyleMandli I'd take the latter as well, as I've seen C-N many times on diffusion-advection equations. The term "Variable coefficient heat equation" comes from the x multiplier in the rhs?

Comment: @KyleMandli, yes the PDEs are identical, but that doesn't imply that their discrete forms are.

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann When you say I will reduce the order of the method, do you refer to the first or the second discretization?

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense. Then the singularity is well away from the integration interval and the midpoint is the appropriate approximation everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the first expression and start to reduce the $x$ values to $x_i$,
\begin{align}
\frac{u_{i+1}^n - u_i^n}{x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}} - \frac{u_i^n - u_{i-1}^n}{x_{i-\frac{1}{2}}}
&=
\frac{(x_i-\frac12Δx)(u_{i+1}^n - u_i^n) - (x_i+\frac12Δx)(u_i^n - u_{i-1}^n)}{x_{i-\frac{1}{2}}x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}}
\\
&=\frac{x_i}{x_i^2-\frac14Δx^2}(u_{i+1}^n - 2u_i^n + u_{i-1}^n) 
\\&\qquad
    - \frac{Δx}{2(x_i^2-\frac14Δx^2)}(u_{i+1}^n - u_{i-1}^n)
\end{align}
After multiplying with $rx_i$ you find that the difference to the second formula are only in terms of size $O(Δx^2)$, that is, within the error order of the method.

Comment: So, in terms of order of accuracy, there is no preference? Any other things to account for when choosing one or the other?

Comment: I do not see anything that could be quantitatively different. The computed numbers will differ of course, but within the bounds of the method error.